# laravel csrf in javascript return The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I have a code for the delete data loop in a table. 
this can be used, and works.

```html
@foreach ($datasiswa as $a)

<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aktifMagang{{ $a->id }}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Aktifkan Magang</a>
<!-------- start Modal --->
<div id="aktifMagang{{ $a->id }}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-aqua">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Daftarkan Magang</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{route('magang.odin.akftikanmagang',['id'=>$a->id])}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                    {{ csrf_field()}} Aktifkan <strong>{{ $a->user->name }}</strong> sebagai peserta magang ?
                    <input type="hidden" name="siswa_id" value="{{ $a->id }}">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aktifkan</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

but the results will make every data a modal.
if I have  100 data then there should be 100 modal.

Is there a way to make it a single modal?

searching ... and i found this .

```html
@foreach ($datasiswa as $a)
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#aktifMagang" data-siswaid="{{ $a->id }}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Aktifkan Magang
</a><br /> 
@endforeach
```

then

```html
<div id="aktifMagang" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-aqua">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Daftarkan Magang</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{route('magang.odin.akftikanmagang',['id'=>$a->id])}}" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                    Aktifkan <strong class="namasiswa"></strong> sebagai peserta magang ?
                    <input type="hidden" name="siswa_id" value="">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aktifkan</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then add another

```html
<script>
  $('#aktifMagang').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var recipient = button.data('siswaid') 
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.namasiswa').text(namasiswa)
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
  })
</script>
```

but 
The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

Comment: U can use a single modal why do u use a hundred modals? just modify the original modal content before showing it... make a function, this function refresh data from de modal and inserts de new data, and then you call the function that shows de modal. 100 modals is 0 practical approach

Comment: formatting fixes

Comment: im sorry .. and i edit my question.